# Limits and Integration Recursion

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

[image: Limit Problems]

I was able to obtain an answer of $k/(k+1)$ for part 1, by interchanging the limit and sum and then evaluating the limit of the integrand. However, for part (2), I'm stuck because using the same idea from part (1), I obtain an infinity - infinity indeterminate form. The substitution x = u^(n^-2) didn't help much either. Any help for parts (1) and (2) would be appreciated.

[image: My Progress]

Answer (score 1):

We can use the series expansion

$$\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n \sim e^t-\frac{t^2e^t}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

for large $n$ and

$$L=\int_0^1 x^{\frac{1}{k}}dx,$$

to get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\int_0^1\left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}+k-1}{k}\right)^ndx-L\right) = -\int_0^1\frac{\log^2x}{2k^2}x^{\frac{1}{k}}dx$$

$$=-\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{s}{k}}dx \Bigr|_{s=1} = \frac{-k}{(k+1)^3}$$

by Feynman's trick.

Comment: The integrand is incorrect, it should be x^1/n not x^1/k.

Comment: @LadderSetsOnly $n$ is the limit variable, it should not appear after the limit is taken

Comment: @NinadMunshi I believe you forgot a (k-1) factor at some point

Comment: the answer should be (k)(k-1)/(1+k)^3

Comment: @NinadMunshi see this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3E+inf+%28%28%28-1+%2B+k+%2B+x%5E%281%2Fn%29%29%2Fk%29%5En+%28-%28x%5E%281%2Fn%29+log%28x%29%29%2F%28n+%28-1+%2B+k+%2B+x%5E%281%2Fn%29%29%29+%2B+log%28%28-1+%2B+k+%2B+x%5E%281%2Fn%29%29%2Fk%29%29%29*%28-n%5E2%29

Comment: @SanjoyKundu where are you getting this from, and can you explain what you mean by the link?

Comment: @NinadMunshi When you combine the two integrals and move the limit inside, the limit of the integrand equals this, not what you obtained above. Then as the limit goes to infinity, you have (k-1)/2k^2 times the integral of x^(1/k)*ln^2(x) from 0 to 1, and the rest follows. Your answer was essentially missing a (k-1) factor and should not be negative.

Comment: @Sanjoykundu that's not an answer you basically just said that's the answer because it's the answer. And having this be negative makes perfect sense because the sequence is always strictly less than the limit $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n < e^x$$ for all $n$

Comment: @NinadMunshi If you evaluate the integral from 0 to 1 of the limit as n->infinity of ((x^1/n + k - 1)/(k))^n - (x^1/k)/n, you get a 0/0 indeterminate form. Applying L'Hopitals rule gives you the query I posted. And then evaluating the integral gives you (k)(k-1)/(1+k)^3. Basically what I am saying is combine the two integrals, push the n and the limit as n->infinity inside the integral, evaluate the limit first via L'Hoptial's Rule, and then evaluate the integral from 0 to 1. If you do that you will obtain the result I obtained above. Additionally, the OP of this question followed my work too.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above is my attempt at answering this part. I got something similar to what Sanjoy Kundu suggested.

Comment: How did $n$ become $\frac{1}{n}$ before applying LHopital?

Comment: They probably meant to write 1/n in the denominator. It's a small typo